# Xcode - What is Swapped Size in Allocations Instrument

Tags: xcode

I know that Dirty Size is the size of Dirty Memories created, while Resident Size is the size of Dirty Memory + Clean Memory (Correct me if I am wrong). Then what is this swapped size? I ran the app for a while but no track of swapped memory. I tried googling but nothing came out.

[image]

Comment: Watch WWDC 2013 Session 410.

Comment: A follow-up question would be why Swapped Size sometimes is > 0 on iOS which officially does not support swapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the amount of your application's memory that has been [paged out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) to disk to make room for other data.

Unless your application is using a *lot* of memory, this should always be zero.